# Yocto Project not install files properly

Tags: mariadb, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to create a recipe for the C/C++ Connector of MariaDB.

Bitbake works without errors or warnings but if I checked the files in my image there are two missing:

- libmariadbclient.a
- libmariadb.so

There are both in different packages (-dev and -staticdev) but for whatever reason there are not shipped to my image.

Does someone has a solution?

Here is the recipe:

```
 LICENSE = "BSD"
 LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING.LIB;md5=4fbd65380cdd255951079008b364516c \
                file://win/packaging     /license.rtf;md5=0b6c50a153e2fca0364c97805d74ba50 \
                file://cmake/COPYING-CMAKE-SCRIPTS;md5=54c7042be62e169199200bc6477f04d1"

SRC_URI = "http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb//connector-c-3.0.2/mariadb-connector-c-3.0.2-src.tar.gz;name=source"

SRC_URI[source.md5sum] = "2eb5ba004ac105eebb538ead352c0c78"
SRC_URI[source.md256sum] = "518d14b8d77838370767d73f9bf1674f46232e1a2a34d4195bd38f52a3033758"

S = "${WORKDIR}/mariadb-connector-c-3.0.2-src"

DEPENDS = "zlib openssl gnutls krb5 curl"

PACKAGES =+"${PN}-include"

FILES_${PN}+="${libdir}/mariadb/libmariadb.so.3 \
    ${libdir}/mariadb/plugin/dialog.so \
    ${libdir}/mariadb/plugin/mysql_clear_password.so \
    ${libdir}/mariadb/plugin/remote_io.so \
    ${libdir}/mariadb/plugin/auth_gssapi_client.so \
    ${bindir}/mariadb_config"

FILES_${PN}-dev+="${libdir}/mariadb/libmariadb.so"

FILES_${PN}-staticdev+="${libdir}/mariadb/libmariadbclient.a"

FILES_${PN}-include+="${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb_com.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mysql.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb_stmt.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/ma_pvio.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/ma_tls.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb_version.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/ma_list.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/errmsg.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb_dyncol.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb_ctype.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mysqld_error.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mysql/client_plugin.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mysql/plugin_auth_common.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mysql/plugin_auth.h \
    ${includedir}/mariadb/mariadb/ma_io.h "

RDEPENDS_${PN}+="${PN}-include"

inherit cmake

do_compile() {
    make
}
```

Comment: They aren't shipped on your image because no other package in your image has a runtime dependency on those packages. Are you _really_ sure something in your image needs those files? static libs and dev files typically are not part of a target image.

Comment: So the `-dev` and `-staticdev` packages are not included in my image? I need them since I have some source to compile. Without them I got errors. How can I include them in my final image? I know, it is not common

Comment: Do you really mean that you want to compile your sources *on* your target? I'd prefer to compile on my build machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding just a specific package to image can be done with e.g. `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mariadb-dev"` in your local.conf (or image recipe). It sounds like you want to compile something on device so this is unlikely to do what you want (you'd still be missing all the development tools and and all the other -dev packages you need).

I wouldn't really suggest developing on the image (why not write a recipe for your app and let Yocto handle the compiling and installing instead?) but if you want to do it, adding this in local.conf should work:

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "dev-pkgs tools-sdk"
```

This adds build tools (gcc, make, etc) and all -dev packages to the image. See [the manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-imagefeatures) for more details.